# a word describing the action of providing (any) information with the given intent of informing?

Tags: single-word-requests

Sometimes people say something with no true intention to inform their audience but for a covert intention other than that. In such cases, we may say, the information, as well as the informant, is *manipulative*. For example, we are told by the producer that a product has such and such good points, while her real intention is to make us buy it, and not just to let us know that the product has such and such good points.

Some other times people say something *just* to inform their intended audience, to share whit her what they think as true; they *simply* want their audience to know about whatever it is they are talking about. In such cases, information is not manipulative, it is just for the sake of informing, just for the sake of sharing the truth with the audience, just to let her know the thing whatever it is. What is a right word (adjective) to describe such kind of information.

Some examples are parents who inform their children in order to let them know things, good teacher when they inform students, and doctors when they inform patients.

One may simply say "non-manipulative information", but then it also covers unintentional information too. Besides, if we call it "truthful information", then manipulative information sometimes is true/truthful too.

So what we call a piece of information that is truly for informing.

Comment: Well, the other 'information' might be 'backstory' or 'context'

Comment: @marcellothearcane What other information ?

Comment: The non-manipulative type.  I think you'd be interested in [pragmatics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatics)

Comment: One word for that would be *raving,* as in the ravings of a lunatic. Kierkegaard in *Either/Or* posits a guy who goes around declaring the earth to be round, absent any rhetorical purpose for saying that, and finds this to be stark lunacy even though his proposition is in fact true.

Comment: @marcellothearcane You mean like when you tell somebody a proposition but you want her to know something other than what that proposition actually mean? Like when I ask you if Jack is a good person and you answer he has a good handwriting, intending to tell me that you think he is not a good person.

Comment: @Sasan that's [damning by faint praise](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/damn+with+faint+praise)

Comment: A difficulty of finding an acceptable word or phrase for this is that you're not describing a property of the information but of the speaker's intent or of the information's impact on the receiver. As mentioned above this is a question of pragmatics and, specifically, [speech acts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_act). I would say such information is the products of statements in which the primary illocutionary force was assertive or informative.

Comment: "straight talk" comes to mind, but I think that also has connotations of speech "with no frills", as opposed to just making a statement about the truth of what is being said. EDIT: Never mind, that can't be used to describe *information* anyway.

Comment: Surely 'letting people know good things' is trying to influence them towards good choices and lifestyle. Informing people of basic facts is part of education.

Comment: You question asks what to call such *information*. But the information itself says nothing about *why* it is given - the **intent**. You can provide **any** information with either intent. Seems like you really should be asking for a word indicating the *action of providing* (any) information *with the given intent* (of informing). As it stands now, the question is unclear or, well, a bit misguided.

Comment: @Drew You are right. I am asking for a word indicating the action of providing (any) information with the given intent (of informing). But then that word could be used for the information involved. right? I am gonna change the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was ***informative*** but you seem to have discounted that in favor of something informative that is specifically provided without purpose, perhaps other than an ***educational*** (my next thought) purpose.

I've heard the term *pure research* used as the opposite of *applied research*, so I looked into that and found a Wikipedia article on *[basic research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_research)* (same as pure research).

So, perhaps you could use ***[pure information](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pure)*** or, as suggested by the Wikipedia article, ***[fundamental](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fundamental)***.

Lastly, I thought of ***[abstract](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/abstract)*** as in:

> 1.2 Not based on a particular instance; theoretical.

Hopefully, one of these can at least get you closer to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for *enlightenment* or *wisdom*? Both of these retain a positive connotation.

Comment: But the title asks for a neutral informing, bare facts. Telling someone that the Elbonians have a water-polo tournament next month is merely peddling facts.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think of **signification** ? :
1. Meaning or significance, especially of a word.
2. The action or process of signifying: a theory of signification.
http://www.thefreedictionary.com/signification